# データベースの各テーブルに対してパスワードを設定することは可能？

Tags: mysql

mysql等のDBではデータベース毎ではなくテーブル毎にパスワードをかけることはできますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

データベースやテーブルに対してパスワードを設定するのではなく、あくまで **アカウントに対して** パスワードを付与して権限を管理します。

権限は以下のようなレベルに応じて参照/変更などを設定することができます。

(代表的なもの)

- データベースレベル
- テーブルレベル
- カラムレベル

参考:
[ユーザーに設定できる権限の種類と一覧](https://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/user/index5.html#section1)

Comment: ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

MySQLではテーブルごとに透過的テーブルスペース暗号化することができます。
[テーブルごとのファイルテーブルスペースの暗号化](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/innodb-data-encryption.html#innodb-data-encryption-enabling-disabling)

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT) ENCRYPTION = 'Y';
```

この仕組みで簡単にデータベースファイルを暗号化できるので、ファイル自体を盗まれたり悪用するためにダウンロードされても読めません。
ただしSQL文を発行して中身を読むことは防げないのでSQLインジェクションなどの対策にはなりません。

参考: [MySQL と MariaDB のテーブルスペース暗号化について](https://blog.s-style.co.jp/2017/06/783/)

Comment: ありがとうございます